# Serialize XML same tag twice

Tags: c#, .net, xml, exception, xml-serialization

I've the problem:

I have to serialize class to XML file. But two properties must be named with the same name:

Desired xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Test>
  <HeaderText>
    <Tag1>AAA</Tag1>
  </HeaderText>
  <HeaderText>
    <Tag2>BBB</Tag2>
  </HeaderText>
</Test>
```

I don't need to deserialize it back to object.

Code:

```
public class Header1
{
    [XmlElement("Tag1")]
    public String Tag1 { get; set; }
}

public class Header2
{
    [XmlElement("Tag2")]
    public String Tag2 { get; set; }
}

public class Test
{
    [XmlElement("HeaderText")]
    public Header1 Header1 { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("HeaderText")]
    public Header2 Header2 { get; set; }
}

var doc = new Test
{
    Header1 = new Header1 { Tag1 = "AAA" },
    Header2 = new Header2 { Tag2 = "BBB" }
};

var xml = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Test));
using (var fs = new FileStream("test.xml", FileMode.Create))
{
    xml.Serialize(fs, doc);
}
```

This code doesn't work.

> The XML element 'HeaderText' from namespace '' is already present in the current scope. Use XML attributes to specify another XML name or namespace for the element.

What can I do?

**Real-world example:**

```
  <Product>
    <RecordReference>1-15991</RecordReference>
    <MainSubject>
      <MainSubjectSchemeIdentifier>66</MainSubjectSchemeIdentifier>
      <SubjectCode>2</SubjectCode>
    </MainSubject>
    <MainSubject>
      <MainSubjectSchemeIdentifier>20</MainSubjectSchemeIdentifier>
      <SubjectHeadingText>Venäläisiä kirjoja: uskonto, teosofia, mystiikka</SubjectHeadingText>
    </MainSubject>
</Product>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use an array:

```
public class Test
{
    [XmlElement("HeaderText")]
    public string[] HeaderText { get; set; }
}
```

and then:

```
var doc = new Test
{
    HeaderText = new[] { "AAA", "BBB" }
};
var xml = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Test));
using (var fs = new FileStream("test.xml", FileMode.Create))
{
    xml.Serialize(fs, doc);
}
```

Also works with `List<string>`.

---

UPDATE:

With complex objects you define a model:

```
public class Header
{
    public string Tag { get; set; }
}
```

and then you have a collection of this model:

```
public class Test
{
    [XmlElement("HeaderText")]
    public Header[] HeaderText { get; set; }
}
```

and then you serialize:

```
var doc = new Test
{
    HeaderText = new[] 
    { 
        new Header { Tag = "AAA" }, 
        new Header { Tag = "BBB" }
    }
};
var xml = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Test));
using (var fs = new FileStream("test.xml", FileMode.Create))
{
    xml.Serialize(fs, doc);
}
```

Comment: Also works with `public List<string> HeaderText {}`, easier to Add/Remove items.

Comment: @Tisho, yeap, I have updated my answer to include this information.

Comment: Thanks, it works for simple properties. Please see updated code in question.

Comment: :( I have different classes with different properties (Header1, Header2).

Comment: That seems a wrong approach. In the XML you have shown you seem to want to represent a collection. So this is what I would recommend you using in your models. If you don't do that you might need to write lots of plumbing code.

Answer (score 8):

You could tell the serializer to ignore your current properties, and add a new one for the purpose of serialization:

```
public class Test
{
    [XmlIgnore]
    public String Header1 { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public String Header2 { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("HeaderText")]
    public String[] HeaderText
    {
        get{  return new[]{Header1,Header2};   }
        set{  if(value.Length == 2) { Header1 = value[0]; Header2 = value[1];} }
    }
}
```

Live example: http://rextester.com/YVEF64085