# 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Xml.Serialization.ni.dll

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-8.1, linkedin-api, xmlserializer

I am making a Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight Application. I want **LinkedIn Authentication** in it. I got 1-3 samples from internet. but they all are reporting error on same line:

```
using System.Xml.Serialization;
personXerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SampleLinkedApp.Data.person));
```

**Giving me Error:**

> *An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Xml.Serialization.ni.dll but was not handled in user code
>   Additional information: There was an error reflecting type
>   'SampleLinkedApp.Data.person'.*

Also,
**person.cs:**

```
[XmlRoot("person")]
    public class person
    {      
        [XmlElement("first-name")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("last-name")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("headline")]
        public string Headline { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("headline")]
        public string Interests { get; set; }
    }
```

Where Is the problem?

---

Also adding inner exception to this question:

```
    {System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error reflecting property 'Interests'. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: The XML element 'headline' from namespace '' is already present in the current scope. Use XML attributes to specify another XML name or namespace for the element.
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.AddUniqueAccessor(INameScope scope, Accessor accessor)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.AddUniqueAccessor(MemberMapping member, INameScope elements, INameScope attributes, Boolean isSequence)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.InitializeStructMembers(StructMapping mapping, StructModel model, Boolean openModel, String typeName, RecursionLimiter limiter)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.InitializeStructMembers(StructMapping mapping, StructModel model, Boolean openModel, String typeName, RecursionLimiter limiter)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportStructLikeMapping(StructModel model, String ns, Boolean openModel, XmlAttributes a, RecursionLimiter limiter)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportTypeMapping(TypeModel model, String ns, ImportContext context, String dataType, XmlAttributes a, Boolean repeats, Boolean openModel, RecursionLimiter limiter)}
```

Comment: I used : http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/LinkedIn_authentication_and_own_basic_profile_view_using_Hammock

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It tells you...

> The XML element 'headline' from namespace '' is already present in the current scope. Use XML attributes to specify another XML name or namespace for the element.

So look at:

```
[XmlElement("headline")]
public string Headline { get; set; }

[XmlElement("headline")]
public string Interests { get; set; }
```

They can't *both* be `<headline>`, because when deserializing it would have no way of knowing which to use when seeing `<headline>foo</headline>`. Now, you could argue "but I only want to serialize", but `XmlSerializer` doesn't trust folks to work that way: it will only serialize models that it thinks it can also deserialize.

At a guess, you want something like:

```
[XmlElement("interests")]
public string Interests { get; set; }
```

Comment: If you want two elements with the same name, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11290705/1438809) helped me, which uses a list.